# Import CSV, exclude first row

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import-from-excel

I'm importing my csv fine now except one thing, how do i get the import to ignore the data in the first row? Employees will be uploading the same format which has the column names in that first row.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File " . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . " uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import = "INSERT into tictoc(employee,taskname,tasktime,sessiontime,sessionstart,sessionend,sessionnotes) values('" . $userinfo['first_name'] . " " . $userinfo['last_name'] . "','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";
}
```

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/623041), into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain).  In particular, the uploaded file could contain SQL that will be injected into your `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 7):

just set a variable `$i = 0`  Then only insert when `$i = 1` or more

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $i=0; //so we can skip first row

    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($i>0) {
            $import="INSERT into tictoc(employee,taskname,tasktime,sessiontime,sessionstart,sessionend,sessionnotes) values('".$userinfo['first_name']." ".$userinfo['last_name']."','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";
}
```

Comment: The first row contains the header content though

Comment: @Hector But you question is how to skip the first row.  see updated answer

Comment: This is actually bad form, to have a conditional check inside a loop which could be handled by simply reading in one line prior to the loop. No need for  counter or loop on the condition.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) command, which will be [considerably faster](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-speed.html) than parsing the CSV into PHP, constructing an `INSERT` statement for every record, submitting it as a string to MySQL and having MySQL parse said string for SQL (at risk of SQL injection):

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE tictoc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(tasktime, sessiontime, sessionstart, sessionend, sessionnotes)
SET employee = ?, taskname = ?
```

Using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
  $qry = $dbh->prepare('
    LOAD DATA INFILE :filepath INTO TABLE tictoc
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (tasktime, sessiontime, sessionstart, sessionend, sessionnotes)
    SET employee = :employee, taskname = :taskname
  ');

  $qry->execute(array(
    ':filepath' => $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],
    ':employee' => $userinfo['first_name'],
    ':taskname' => $userinfo['last_name']
  ));
}
```

Comment: this can't be use by php remotely on client computer.

Comment: @wlin: Use the `LOCAL` modifier.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use this way if you like:

```
$i=0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $i++;
    if($i==1) continue;

    $import="INSERT into tictoc(employee,taskname,tasktime,sessiontime,sessionstart,sessionend,sessionnotes) values('".$userinfo['first_name']." ".$userinfo['last_name']."','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

     mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No variable needed. It is much simpler than this. Here is a solution that requires the least amount of foreign code, and works just fine. Try putting:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
```

Before your while() loop that grabs the CSV data. That grabs the headers, but leaves them out from being inserted into the database. Once the while loop begins, the first line has already been returned thus leaving them out of the mysql insert. On top of this it appears the headers were needed and so this solves that as well.

So in the end,

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File " . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . " uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    //Grab the headers before doing insertion
    $headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import = "INSERT into tictoc(employee,taskname,tasktime,sessiontime,sessionstart,sessionend,sessionnotes) values('" . $userinfo['first_name'] . " " . $userinfo['last_name'] . "','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
array_shift($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have implement this code and it is tested code. I think it is very use full

You have follow some rule:-

1.your csv file according to database table name (ex: db table name is users then csv should be users.csv)

2.Your csv file's first row should be db table fields name (ex: Id, name etc) after the start your data entry

3.you can download data source class from :- http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/ because i have require below the code: require_once 'CSV/DataSource.php';

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "excel_import";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

$conn=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("I cannot connect to the database because: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to select database because: " . mysql_error());


require_once 'CSV/DataSource.php';


$filename = "users.csv";
$ext = explode(".",$filename);
$path = "uploads/".$filename;

$dbtable = $ext[0];

import_csv($dbtable, $path);


function import_csv($dbtable, $csv_file_name_with_path)
{
    $csv = new File_CSV_DataSource;
    $csv->load($csv_file_name_with_path);

    $csvData = $csv->connect();

    $res='';
    foreach($csvData  as $key)
    {
        $myKey ='';
        $myVal='';
        foreach($key as $k=>$v)
        {
            $myKey .=$k.',';
            $myVal .="'".$v."',";
          }

        $myKey = substr($myKey, 0, -1);
        $myVal = substr($myVal, 0, -1); 
        $query="insert into ".$dbtable." ($myKey)values($myVal)";
        $res=  mysql_query($query);

    }

    if($res ==1)
    {

                echo "record successfully Import.";

    }else{

                echo "record not successfully Import.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare one variable before `while` loop

```
$row=1;
```

then in `while` loop put this condition

```
if($row==1){
   $row++; 
   continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File " . $_FILES['filename']['name'] . " uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
}

//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
fgetcsv($handle); //skip the reading of the first line from the csv file

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT into tictoc(employee,taskname,tasktime,sessiontime,sessionstart,sessionend,sessionnotes) values('" . $userinfo['first_name'] . " " . $userinfo['last_name'] . "','$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);

print "Import done";
```

}